# Sort datetime varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for some help. I have a date field as datetime YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS and I need it to be a DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. Then I used convert(varchar) but can't order by desc, show this:

```
31/01/2019 17:00:00:000
31/01/2019 17:00:00:000
18/01/2019 13:30:00:000
18/01/2019 13:30:00:000
07/02/2019 03:00:00:000
07/02/2019 03:00:00:000
14/02/2019 12:00:00:000

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ISNULL(tbl_date1,tbl_date2),103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ISNULL(tbl_date1,tbl_date2),14)
```

I dont know how to do this in sql. I have tired cast, and convert, and I keep getting same results.

I have been searching, and trying different methods, just not getting results. Any help would be so appreicated, thank you!

Comment: You can sort by the DATETIME value while returning the formatted VARCHAR value.

Comment: You do not have to order by the varchar column, you can create the varchar column as output and still order by the original datetime column. I assume that is what is wrong but not sure because I do not see the actual query.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but I get the same problem as before:
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Comment: Again, you need to include the actual full query that is producing that error message. That last line of code is not a query that would produce that error message.

Comment: Yes, sure. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
     ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ISNULL(tbl_date1,tbl_date2),103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ISNULL(tbl_date1,tbl_date2),14)
FROM ...
ORDER BY ISNULL(tbl_date1,tbl_date2) DESC
```

Comment: @BRKZ just add `ISNULL(tbl_date1,tbl_date2)` to your `SELECT` query - for example as last column.

Comment: It's a good way. But this report It will be to download to excel and run macros automatically. Has another way to fix this?

Comment: @BRKZ Then, no way to exclude the column from the list when DISTINCT is used.